# OpServer shows blank login screen using vanity URL or Computer name

Tags: opserver

I am able to run OpServer using localhost but when using computer name or a vanity URL I get a blank page. The URL for the blank page is http://VANITYURL.com/login?ReturnUrl=%2f

Here is my SecuritySettings.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SecuritySettings provider="AD">
</SecuritySettings>
```

Just to clarify, I have OpServer working using localhost. I have only enabled the SQL Server dashboard.

Issue appears to be around the forms authentication. If I enable Windows Authentication I am forced to the login screen even after login. Once I try to login, I disable Windows Authentication and refresh the browser and I am now able to access the site.

Ok, adding additional info. When debugging the entry seems to be Application_BeginRequest() and when it exits it goes to Application_EndRequest().

Comment: I think these questions are related:

http://serverfault.com/questions/331139/why-can-i-browse-to-localhost-not-to-my-computer-name-iis7

http://serverfault.com/questions/331139/why-can-i-browse-to-localhost-not-to-my-computer-name-iis7

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting this as the root site, like `http://VANITYURL.com/` or is it actually a virtual directory or application like `http://VANITYURL.com/Opserver/`?
It looks like the latter case is not directly supported: https://github.com/opserver/Opserver/issues/24
Problem being that if you host at `/opserver/` or whatever, they still hardcode redirects to `/login` instead of `/opserver/login`
Their suggested solution to that is a custom host binding, like to `http://opserver.VANITYURL.com/` which I think what @HerbalMart is referring to.

Comment: The site is hosted at the root at it own vanity URL. I was able to work around for now by turning on Anonymous Authentication and Forms Authentication. This is not much of an issue since the site is internal only.